# Blocking Users from Repeating Animations Continuously

Tags: jquery

I have a button that toggles some text to fade in/out.

After I've clicked the button madly (say 15 times), I can sit and watch the text continually fade in and out 15 times until it stops.

I'm looking for a solution that will prevent users from doing that; which I've been calling looping or stacking animations.

My original attempt:

```
$( "h2" ).click(function(){
    $( this ).toggleClass( "someRed" );
    $( "p" ).fadeToggle( "slow" );
});
```

[Here that is on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LGHpc/)

Thanks. This feels very basic :(

*I looked into stop() and clearQueue() and those methods aren't suiting my needs. I hate posting on SO, but I've spent 2 hours looking for solutions and no luck.*

I also tried adding an animation counter, but it still allows looping/stacking:

```
var hoverState = 0;
    $( "h2:first" ).bind("click", function(){
    showContent();
});

function showContent(){
    if(hoverState == 0) {
        hoverState = 1;

    $( "h2:first" ).toggleClass( "someRed" );
    $( ".expInfo" ).fadeToggle( "slow" );       
    }
    hoverState = 0;
};
```

Comment: i would leave user to do it - if it makes him happy. :) Limiting of number of clicks isn't option, i guess?

Comment: Maybe I could attach a delay() to the hoverState = 0; reset at the end?

Comment: Count how many times the button has been clicked and if it's been click so many times then prevent animation from starting.  If you still need them to work later on then count how many clicks with in a time period and if its at a certain threshold then prevent animation.

Answer (score 1):

What, i always learned to do is, make a `display:none` overlay-div over your button. When the animation starts, activate the invisible div that goes OVER the button, being the same size of the button. When someone clicks now, they don't click the button, but the invisible div, resulting in no animation. Then, after the animation has ended, you can put the overlay back to `display:none`, waiting for the next click on the button. :)

EDIT: I see you are using fadeToggle. From https://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/:

```
   //On click H2:
   $('#overlay').css('display','block');
   $( "trigger" ).fadeToggle( "fast", function() {
    // When the animation is finished
    $('#overlay').css('display','none');

  });
```

Now you just have to position div#overlay over h2 and you should be good to go :)